# Modify the preferences of chrome with C#

Tags: c#, .net, google-chrome, toolbar, preferences

I am developing an application in c # to modify the file "Preferences" of chrome.
The problem is when I want to overwrite the file

```
~Users\"User"\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Preferences
```

for some reason not rewritten, but it works fine.

If I delete the file manually, the file disappears. If the application removes the file reappears ..

In the manifest I have declared

`<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />`

What could be the problem in which the file is deleted and reappear, or it may be rewritten?

Comment: `What could be the problem in which the file is deleted and reappear, or it may be rewritten?` I am *so* confused

Comment: The problem is that if the application deletes the file, automatically reappears, and if you manually delete does not reappear. It will be a permission problem?